# Bukkit plugin syntax error : Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody

Tags: java, syntax, bukkit

Here is my code. The last curly bracket at the bottom has the error. This is very annoying and I have been trying to fix it. Is it that I have too much bracets or something? I'm really stumped. Please help.

```
    enter code here

package me.sapita.medic;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class medicplugin1 extends JavaPlugin {


    public void onEnable() {
        Bukkit.getServer().getLogger().info("Medic enabled!");
    }

    public void onDisable() {
        Bukkit.getServer().getLogger().info("Medic disabled!");
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args){

    if (!(sender instanceof Player)){
        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "The console cannot be regenerated!");
        return true;
    }

    Player player = (Player) sender;


    if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("regen")){
        Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);
        if (target == null){
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Could not find user.");
            return true;
        }

        if (args.length == 0){
            player.setHealth(20);
            player.setFoodLevel(20);
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "Your health & food have been regenerated!");
        }
        if (target == null){
            player.sendMessage("Please specify a player to regenerate.");
        }

        sender.sendMessage(target.getName() + "has been regenerated!");

        target.setHealth(20);
        target.sendMessage(sender.getName()+ "has regenerated your health & food!");
        return true;

        }

    return true;

    if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("resetfood")){

        Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);
    if (target == null){
        player.setFoodLevel(20);
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "Your food health has been regenerated!");
        return true;
    }

    if (args.length == 0){
        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "You have fed yourself!");

        player.setFoodLevel(20);
        return true;
    }


    target.setFoodLevel(20);



    target.sendMessage(sender.getName() + "has regenerated your food!");

    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + target.getName() + "has been food health has been regenerated!");{
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: This is one of the reasons not to use 'Java opening {' style - put opening brace on the next line - indent everything and you'll see where your problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing two "}" at the end of the file.

1. public boolean onCommand()
2. class medicplugin1

The third one, which jpw mentioned is actually a problem with an opening brace, as I think you want to return `true` at the end of the if-clause.

```
sender.sendMessage( ... ); ---> { <---
    return true;
}
```

Consider using your IDEs code formatter next time, as they will most likly show you problems like this.

Further ...

```
   if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("regen")){ ... }

   return true;

   if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("resetfood")){ ... ]
```

This code seems wrong .. as this would resolve in an UnreachableCode error at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

You're actually missing three (3) `}` at the end. Proper indentation would have made this obvious very fast.

The blocks missing closing brackets are:

`if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("resetfood"))`

`public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args)`

`public class medicplugin1 extends JavaPlugin`